# ThreadPoolTaskScheduler run tasks and why future is same?

Tags: java, threadpool

This is `treadpooltaskscheduler` code:

```
@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;

private ScheduledFuture<?> future;

@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
     threadPoolTask.setPoolSize(10);
     return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
}
```

this is task start and stop service code:

```
public void taskStartService(int id) {
    Optional<Task> taskOptional = taskRepository.findById(id);
    if (taskOptional.isPresent()) {
        future = threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(() -> {
              System.out.println("task-" + id + ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", " + future);
        }, new CronTrigger(taskOptional.get().getTaskTime()));
    }
}
public void taskStopService(int id){
    if (taskRepository.findById(id).isPresent()) {
        if (future != null) {
            future.cancel(true);
        }
}
```

when I run application,and run 2 tasks, and i print "future", i find "future" is same

Comment: provide the code that calls `taskStartService`

Comment: @Deadpool just calls it in controller(/task/start/{id})

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a

```
Thread.sleep(10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default threadPoolSize = 1. So your tasks runs within one thread.

You should use `setPoolSize` to set thread pool size.

Comment: thanks, i tried set poolsize=10  and i also see create multipl thread ,  but why every task is same?

Comment: i consoled log my every future   the future is same   Lambda$1113/0x0000000800aba840@1e9cca7d   why?

Comment: how to  stop task-1 and not stop task-2? @RoninDev

Comment: Are your tasks run simultaneously? Can you provide more code?

Comment: just these code,i don`t know why tasks is same when i print future in taskStartService

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` is not java provided class. So I assume it is either a third party class or your own class. The right place to deal with this issue is in your code:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
     return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
}
```

If class `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` has a constructor that takes the number of threads (as it should) just specify it there or if there is a separate setter method for the number of threads than change the code above to first create an instance and then set the number of threads. So it would be something like:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
     return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler(10);
}
```

or

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
     ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
     threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreads(10)
     return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

case 1：Your ThreadPoolTaskScheduler size is 1

case 2: Your task execution time is too short

You can provide more code?

Comment: hi,thanks for your  answer, i resolve size,but i find "future" is same,can you tell me the reason?